# Get dimensions programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am writing an Android application with Xamarin.Android. I am trying to get the dimensions programmatically like this:

```
float dim = Resources.System.GetDimensionPixelSize(Resource.Dimension.my_dim);
```

And I get this error:

> Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException has been thrown

But I see on other questions on SO that this should work...any idea why it wouldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with Xamarin.Android, only standard Android, but I believe that this will still answer your question.

The `Resources.getSystem()` call (which I assume is the equivalent of your `Resources.System` property) returns a `Resources` object that can only access *system* resources. This `Resources` object **cannot** access application resources or resources that depend on the screen and/or screen configuration... including dimensions.

From the stock Android documentation:

> Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to only system resources (no application resources), and is not configured for the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based on orientation, etc).

You will need to get your hands on a `Resources` object in some manner other than `Resources.System` if you want to access dimensions. If you have a `Context` object, you can use the `Resources` public property of the context.

Comment: Correct. The correct way of getting a dimension from your `dimensions.xml` is `float dim = Context.Resources.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.my_dim)`